# PHP: references in assignment

Tags: php

I'm not a guru in PHP, but I used the language enough to know a lot of quirks and oddities of its syntax and built-in functions. But this is new to me:

```
$ok = is_acceptable($_SESSION['config']);
$config = $ok ? &$_SESSION['config'] : retrieve_config();
```

The compiler tells me that `&` is unexpected. Wrapping `&$_SESSION['config']` in parenthesis won't change anything, so I had to resolve to this:

```
if ($ok) $config = &$_SESSION['config'];
else $config = retrieve_config();
```

The alternative is to drop `&` altogether, but that would make a copy of the value and I tend to avoid that.

Why is that syntax wrong? Out of curiosity. My bet is that `&` is mistaken as the `and` bitwise operator.

Comment: Why you need to use reference in this case?

Comment: @hindmost For whatever reason. The question is not about the convenience of using a reference or not.

Comment: @DanielA.White It's an array or, at least, it's supposed to be. But I get a syntax error, so it's not a runtime error.

Comment: You are assigning the result of the ternary operator. So this would not work as desired even if the syntax is accepted. Copy would be created.

Comment: @Marek I guess that falls under my less-than-perfect understanding of PHP's references. Are you basically saying that `&` can only be used as the "top-most" operator in assignments?

Comment: @MaxArt Not even that. Also `$config = &"abc"` is invalid. You should think of it as `=&` operator where the right side must be variable.

Comment: @Marek Of course, `&` would only work with variables, that was given for granted. If you put it in the form of an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$config = $ok ? &$_SESSION['config'] : retrieve_config();
```

`=` in this case assigns the result of the ternary operator, using reference would not have effect even if the syntax is accepted.

Instead, you should think of it as `=&` operator, where the right side must be always a variable, never an expression. These cases are also invalid:

```
$a =& "abc"; // scalar
$a =& ($b); // expression
```